# Alternatives to Java applets

Tags: java, applet

I'm planning to write a simple program that displays course prerequisites for students at my university in graph form (ie as a network of vertices and edges). I'd like to embed the program in a webpage to save people the hassle of downloading an executable.

Currently I'm looking at making my program a Java applet (Java also would give me access to the handy Swing library), but I don't like the fact that applets can't be viewed on most mobile devices.

What alternatives to applets exist for a project like this? I'd like to make it compatible with as many devices as possible, and also not have to build the graphics stuff from scratch.

One final consideration is I'm doing this mostly as a learning exercise. Ideally the tools I'd be working with would be helpful to know in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066333/alternative-technologies-to-replace-applet

Comment: How dynamic is that program? A graph for course prerequisites sounds like pretty static data. Does it depend on user input? Why make it a program rather than, well, a graphic object generated by the server?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm not sure if I follow that logic. Why would it need to be  generated, rather than served? And what do you mean by a graphic object?

Comment: @popovitsj I mean, it's a graph that's based on data. If the data is static (not dependent on user interaction), it can be generated (either once or based on current data in database etc.) and then served as a non-interactive graphic object, such as a vector image. If it depends on user interaction, that's a different thing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I think the data is probably fairly static, with minor changes every year. I can imagine that it would nice to have some user interaction, because these course prerequisites can get pretty complex... The idea is probably to enable the student to easily figure out what kind of programmes are feasible.

Comment: The data is fairly static, but I want the user to be able to specify the courses they've already taken. Then, based on that information and the prerequisites data the program outputs a graph.

Answer (score 7):

Please don't use applets. They have been sufficiently deprecated.

The best way to do this is by using html/js/css. A lot of useful libraries exist that can help you with this task. jQuery seems obvious, but there's also d3.js or vis.js for displaying visual representations of data, and bootstrap for responsiveness (mobile friendliness).

Comment: I'll have a look at js/html/css. Not too familiar with them, but I guess it's about time I learned more!

Comment: It will be a bit of a learning curve, especially if you're going to do it right and use the appropriate libraries, but "helpful to know in the future" definitely applies.

Answer (score 2):

- You may use [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) with [angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for Showing graph in Web Browser.
- If your graph data is dynamic you might use [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) and [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) for backend.
- [angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) is responsive and its easy to show dynamic graph. But as it uses HTML5 canvas some mobile browsers might not show its transitions smoothly depending on the device.

I personally do not prefer using applet in web browser when the same functionality can be achieved using great frameworks like Angularjs.

Answer (score -2):

why dont you try to build your project through Servlet framework 
by the way cgi were removed by servlet because of the handling of the request 
applet uses the same concept